# nextcloud - client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud

Tags: centos, redhat, owncloud, nextcloud

I am used to install owncloud server on Fedora, but this time I installed nextcloud on CentOS 7. I followed the procedure

```
# yum install nextcloud
# yum install crypto-utils mod_ssl openssl
# genkey hostname

edit

/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

adding

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/hostname.key

let's prepare the database

# yum install mariadb-server
# systemctl enable --now mariadb
$ mysql_secure_installation

$ mysql -u root -p
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nextcloud;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nextcloud.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit

then

# sudo -u apache php occ maintenance:install --data-dir /var/lib/nextcloud/data/ --database "mysql" --database-name "nextcloud"  --database-user "nextcloud" --database-pass "password" --admin-user "admin" --admin-pass "password"

then edit

/etc/owncloud/config.php

and add machine ip address under 'trusted_domains'

# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Unfortunately this time nextcloud does not work, indeed by trying to open

```
https://machine_ip/nextcloud
```

I get

```
Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /nextcloud on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

a few lines of **# cat /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log**

```
[Tue Mar 07 00:51:39.331935 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2456] [client removed_by_me:51184] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud
[Tue Mar 07 00:51:39.331988 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2456] [client removed_by_me:51184] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud/core/templates/403.php
[Tue Mar 07 00:59:19.968622 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2498] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for fe80::removed_by_me:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 07 00:59:20.006434 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2498] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for fe80::removed_by_me:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 07 00:59:30.267154 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2503] [client removed_by_me:51450] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud
[Tue Mar 07 00:59:30.267226 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2503] [client removed_by_me:51450] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud/core/templates/403.php
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:20.574679 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2505] [client removed_by_me:51488] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:20.574931 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2505] [client removed_by_me:51488] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud/core/templates/403.php
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.528960 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] AH02204: Init: Pass phrase incorrect for key of fe80::removed_by_me:443
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529005 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529021 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529032 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529044 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529066 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529077 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Mar 07 01:00:49.529087 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2537] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Tue Mar 07 01:01:12.593572 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2568] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for fe80::removed_by_me:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 07 01:01:12.669001 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2568] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for fe80::removed_by_me:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Mar 07 01:19:01.904878 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2573] [client removed_by_me:55170] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud
[Tue Mar 07 01:19:01.905130 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 2573] [client removed_by_me:55170] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nextcloud/core/templates/403.php
You don't have permission to access /nextcloud on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

[# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/nextcloud.conf](https://da.gd/ByXfH)

[# cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf](https://da.gd/oLVh)

[# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf](https://da.gd/GQdIV)

```
# ls -latr /etc/httpd/conf.d/
total 64
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  691  6 nov 01.32 php.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1252 14 nov 17.53 userdir.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2926 14 nov 19.04 autoindex.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  366 14 nov 19.05 README
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2407  1 mar 02.39 nextcloud-defaults.inc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1893  1 mar 02.39 nextcloud.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  263  1 mar 02.39 nextcloud-auth-none.inc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  313  1 mar 02.39 nextcloud-auth-local.inc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  278  1 mar 02.39 nextcloud-auth-any.inc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  994  1 mar 02.39 nextcloud-access.conf.avail
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 4096  6 mar 13.59 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096  6 mar 17.30 .
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9432  6 mar 17.33 ssl.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  837  7 mar 00.25 welcome.conf


# ls -latr /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/
total 44
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  216  6 nov 01.32 10-php.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  451 14 nov 17.53 01-cgi.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   88 14 nov 17.53 00-systemd.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   41 14 nov 17.53 00-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  957 14 nov 17.53 00-proxy.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  742 14 nov 17.53 00-mpm.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   41 14 nov 17.53 00-lua.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  139 14 nov 17.53 00-dav.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3739 14 nov 17.53 00-base.conf
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 4096  6 mar 13.59 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096  6 mar 17.30 .
```

If you need any other log, please tell me

Comment: So where is your Apache configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
# ln -s /etc/httpd/conf.d/nextcloud-access.conf.avail /etc/httpd/conf.d/z-nextcloud-access.conf
```

Source: lines [7,12] of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/nextcloud.conf`